# Grails, createLink generates wrong link

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I am experiencing a weird issue with createlink. I have this in my gsp

```
<g:createLink controller="uni" action="show" id="1" />
```

I expect it to generate something like

```
"/uni/show/1"
```

However, it actually gives me

```
"/uni/create?id=1"
```

I also tried inline version as well,

```
${createLink(controller:'uni', action:'show', id:1) }
```

this also gives

```
"/uni/create?id=1"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I managed to fix it by adding a url mapping for "show" action

The problem may come from url mapping bug.
I have this defined in my urlmappings.groovy

```
    "/uni/create"(controller:"uni"){
        action = [GET:"create", POST:"createDetail"]
    }
```

This somehow cause it to generate wrong link. I have no idea why, it will be nice if someone can explain it

After I add this line before "create", the problem is gone.

```
    "/uni/show/$id"(controller:"uni",action:"show")
```

Comment: `"/uni/show/$id"(controller:"uni",action:"show")` That helped me, thanks. By the way 9 years later this is still the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have a problem in UrlMappings.groovy .

There are some [open bugs](http://bit.ly/J0nnTn) in reverse url mappings. What Grails version are you using?

The best way to get around some of the bugs is to use [named url mappings](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#namedMappings%5D). In your case that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I am using Grails 2.0. I will check out name url mapping. Thank

Answer (score 0):

if the action is not defined you will get default behavior

http://grails.org/doc/1.1/ref/Tags/createLink.html

action (optional) - The name of the action to use in the link, if not specified the default action will be linked